# Open-Source library for Complete Binary Disassembly

Tags: disassembly, x86

One of the major hurdles of x86 disassembly is separating code from data. All available open-source disassembly library only perform a straight line disassembly (starts from the top and skips errors by 1 byte), compared with OllyDBG which apparently uses a control flow disassembly (using opcodes like CALL and JMP) or IDA using heuristics and emulation. However these two aren't open-source.

My question is, is there any open-source library or project that uses a better technique than simple straight line disassembly (control flow or heuristics based) ?

I stumbled upon a paper using a machine learning approach ? is there an open-source implementation of this approach ?

Comment: I don't know of any open-source libraries for this, but if you want to write your own, see http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2347/what-is-the-algorithm-used-in-recursive-traversal-disassembly

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Radare 2](http://radare.org/) is a GPL software, with a good API, and is not using linear disassembling.

See visual mode (Vp command) example:
[image: example r2 x86 session]

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to have a link or documentation on the disassembly appraoch they are using ?

Comment: @3asm_ Pancake and the rest of the radare2 team. Has the philosophy 'writing-documention is overrated when you can read the source'. Thus, read the source ;)

Comment: @Stolas: well, that sounds similar to the big fat "f... you" the Git docs give *users* trying to merely make use of Git without studying ten semesters of Gitology first.

Comment: @0xC0000022L not sure if you are insulting me or not. But it is understandable that the radare2 team does it. As they want to spend there time write code instead of creating the documentation. Also because when they finished the documentation of radare1 the took got an overhaul... 

I once started with writing the documentation myself, in form of a book (like the animal books of O'Reilly) but it's just too much work.

Comment: @Stolas: am how would I be insulting you? I was referring to the lack of documentation of the project and referring to source code. I disagree it's understandable to skip docs and refer to code since good docs go a long way in making a piece of software accessible to the intended audience. Aside from that I have literally now spent years of maintaining code that is really badly documented where it matters. Heck, I can read the languages used, but it doesn't tell me *why* a certain `if` was introduced or what certain magic numbers means.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I notice I had some issues with the language barrier. I also have stopped using Radare2 due to the lack of documentation. And due to the amount of memory leaks (the code even recognises them as a TODO a number of times).

Comment: @0xC0000022L In fact you can use internal help for radare2 commands - just type '?' and/or '<command name>?'

Comment: @AntonKochkov: cool! Then I won't complain anymore.

Answer (score 6):

I'm reposting my comment which I wrote for perror's [question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2347/what-is-the-algorithm-used-in-recursive-traversal-disassembly)

[Lida](http://lida.sourceforge.net) (a tool based on Bastard's [libdisasm](http://bastard.sourceforge.net/libdisasm.html)), [distorm](http://code.google.com/p/distorm/) and [beaengine](http://www.beaengine.org/home) are some open source disassembly engines that use recursive disassembly.

Comment: Distorm is a linear disassembler AFAIK (used if for several projects)

Answer (score 5):

Another option is (sorry for the spam!) http://pyew.googlecode.com. This is a static analyser written in Python that is used, mainly, for malware analysis. Depending on what you need, you may find it useful (it only supports yet 16, 32 and x64 Intel code). You can write your own scripts using [Pyew's API](https://code.google.com/p/pyew/wiki/BatchExample) (here you have a more complex [example](https://code.google.com/p/pyew/source/browse/gcluster.py)). I use (and used it) for masive malware analysis. Indeed, when I was working for them, Pyew was analysing all the VirusTotal traffic. We used it to discard some very similar looking samples from some expensive analysis.

Pyew does recursive traversal code analysis (explanation [here](https://code.google.com/p/pyew/wiki/CodeAnalysis)). Pyew it's not going to be fooled like linear-sweeps disassemblers. Anyway, it isn't as smart as it's IDA. Pyew is Open Source (GPL) and depending on your needs I even give, sometimes, LGPL licenses for it.

PS: If you're looking for something that support anything which is not Intel based and you want something Open Source you really need to check out [radare](http://radare.org).

Comment: Thanks very insightful, the fact it is in Python will help a lot in my project, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another OpenSource library that might of interest.

[Capstone Engine](http://www.capstone-engine.org)

It supports several architectures, such as x86 (+AMD64), ARM, PowerPC and SPARC.

Comment: Doesn't capstone only use straight line disassembly and is more focused on supporting multiple architectures instead ?