# Automated static code analysis

Tags: ida, ollydbg

Both IDA Pro and OllyDBG automatically analyze the binary on load to identify whats code and data. I assume its a complicated process and I would like to learn more about this process.

How is this process refered to and are you guys aware of any resources about this subject?

I also composed a list of interesting information that can be read from the executable (taken from IDA Pro). Anything to add?

- Names
- Functions

  - Imports
  - Exports
- Strings
- Structures
- Enums
- Segments
- Signatures (To identify the compiler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered at length in The IDA PRO Book by Chris Eagle.

In particular, the entire first chapter is dedicated to this topic.

I would highly recommend purchasing a copy:
https://www.nostarch.com/idapro2.htm

The electronic version is excellent for searching things like this.

Outside of the book, I would recommend consulting this StackExchange question, which discusses Recurisve Descent dissassembly:
[What is the algorithm used in Recursive Traversal disassembly?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2347/what-is-the-algorithm-used-in-recursive-traversal-disassembly)